# Error en carga de listas en Django para avatares

Tags: python, django

tengo un error con las vistas de mi app en Django, quiero cargar la imagen del avatar de la cuenta del usuario. Para eso uso una funcion simple, pero cuando cargo el home me da este resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta son mis views en django:

```
def inicio(request):
    return render(request,"index/index.html", {'user_avatar_url': buscar_url_avatar(request.user)})

def sobre_mi(request):
    return render(request, "index/About.html", {'user_avatar_url': buscar_url_avatar(request.user)})

def buscar_url_avatar(user):
return  Avatar.objects.filter(user=user)[0].imagen.url
```

Y así es como tengo mi codigo HTML, lo quiero configurar para que muestre la imagen en el nav mediante user_avatar_url.

```
                        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href={% url 'logout' %}>Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href={% url 'EditarPerfil' %}>
                            <img src="{{user_avatar_url}}" alt="Editar Usuario" height="20">
                        </a></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href={% url 'login' %}>Inicia Sesion</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href={% url 'register' %}>Registro</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en tu función buscar_url_avatar ya que estas obteniendo el primer objeto con [0] sin antes verificar que tu queryset no este vacío, por eso te dice "list index out of range", una manera de implementarlo seria:

```
def buscar_url_avatar(user):
    avatares = Avatar.objects.filter(user=user)
    if avatares.exists():
        # Se usa first() para obtener el primer objeto
        return avatares.first().imagen.url

    # Si no existe el avatar regresar un None
    return None
```

La manera anterior funciona correctamente si el campo imagen es obligatorio, de otra manera necesitas verificar antes que exista la imagen para devolver la url, seria así:

```
def buscar_url_avatar(user):
    avatares = Avatar.objects.filter(user=user)
    if avatares.exists():
        # Se usa first() para obtener el primer objeto
        if avatares.first().imagen:
            return avatares.first().imagen.url
        else:
            # Existe el avatar pero no tiene imagen
            return None

    # Si no existe el avatar regresar un None
    return None
```

Comment: Me funciono, Un millón de gracias :D